# Sentry for Python: Add "git blame" like prefix to each source code line

Tags: python, sentry, raven

It would be really great if exceptions in sentry would contain info like `git blame` does.

If every line of source code which I see in an exception in sentry would have a prefix like `git blame` (date, commit hash, author) you could find the relevant commit faster.

AFAIK sentry can't do this out of the box. Where and how could I hook into sentry to get this?

Please leave a comment why you down-vote this question. I am curious and willing to learn.

Just for the records. The sentry team is working on something like this. Not exactly, but it does solve the same use case: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/6547

Comment: this looks like a feature request for Sentry, but not a question?

Comment: @georgexsh since I don't know all features which sentry has, I can't distinguish between a feature request or a question.

Comment: I guess you could include at least one question mark in title or body (even if question seems obvious to you).

Comment: @DJV yes, you are right. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to try Guthub Plugin, which doesn't show `git blame`, but integrates with Sentry Releases and show an appropriate commit and author with a link to Github.

https://sentry.io/integrations/github/

Comment: Nice to know that such a plugin exists. Thank you. In my current context the source code is not on github, but in a private (non-github) repo.

Answer (score 1):

A traceback consists of multiple lines of code. You can extract info from `git blame` for each of these lines using the [GitPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) library:

```
import sys
import traceback


from git import Repo


def commit_info(file_path, line_number):
    for commit, lines in Repo().blame('HEAD', file_path):
        line_number -= len(lines)
        if line_number <= 0:
            return commit.hexsha, commit.committed_datetime, commit.author.name


try:
    raise Exception('error')
except Exception:
    for filename, line_number, _, _ in traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2]):
        print filename, line_number, commit_info(filename, line_number)
```

Then, it's up to you how you want to send this information to Sentry. One of the possible solutions is choosing one commit of the list above and using the `extra` keyword and let your logger do the job for you:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception:
    commit = choose_one_commit()
    logger.exception('Error', extra={'author': author.name, 'sha': commit.hexsha})
```

Also, you can use your own logger which would add this `extra` parameter to all `.exception()`, `.error()` and `.critical()` calls.

Overall, it's quite vague what behaviour do you want to achieve, and everything is possible. But calling `git blame` is expensive and may hurt the performance of your application a lot.

Comment: Yes, doing this on the application host would hurt the performance. Is there a way to do this inside sentry (after the data was transferred from the application host to sentry)?

Comment: I believe you can make changes to the Sentry database manually or create a custom plugin, like here: https://docs.sentry.io/server/plugins/#rd-party-plugins. For example, fork and alter the Github plugin @Trilliput told about. There are bitbucket repos, too.